# docker-compose up: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, networking, images

specific error:

```
ERROR: for traefik  Cannot start service traefik: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint frappe_docker_traefik_1 (9403a83dff1da9718f4bbe0bf9c308b7a69093a4aab714a45d542224e8c9679c): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

building the image:

```
root $ 
root $ git config remote.origin.url
https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker.git
root $ 
root $ pwd
/home/nicholas/github/frappe_docker
root $ 
root $ whoami
root
root $ 
root $ docker compose-up
docker: 'compose-up' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
root $ 
root $ 
root $ docker-compose up
Creating network "frappe_docker_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_assets-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_redis-queue-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_redis-cache-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_sites-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_mariadb-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_cert-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_redis-socketio-vol" with default driver
Pulling redis-queue (redis:latest)...
latest: Pulling from library/redis
d121f8d1c412: Already exists
2f9874741855: Pull complete
d92da09ebfd4: Pull complete
bdfa64b72752: Pull complete
e748e6f663b9: Pull complete
eb1c8b66e2a1: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:1cfb205a988a9dae5f025c57b92e9643ec0e7ccff6e66bc639d8a5f95bba928c
Status: Downloaded newer image for redis:latest
Pulling erpnext-worker-long (frappe/erpnext-worker:edge)...
edge: Pulling from frappe/erpnext-worker
522a7372a4ae: Already exists
fe49c307ba58: Pull complete
087f00e219ec: Pull complete
252533adc0db: Pull complete
42192fcae2c8: Pull complete
f9385d54957d: Pull complete
6be927b22c8e: Pull complete
795eed272aec: Pull complete
77889f8e826e: Pull complete
eca6af02605b: Pull complete
d9d9fbb70016: Pull complete
1fec8e8d8c69: Pull complete
4f7588149326: Pull complete
adf49f8e4c64: Pull complete
39eba9b9af97: Pull complete
fc8a4e5ee278: Pull complete
197c0dd2b467: Pull complete
07a1ddc0cbd5: Pull complete
1f848d7ee176: Pull complete
9ff1b5719ccf: Pull complete
8242cccddfed: Pull complete
be819aea4ac8: Pull complete
f3bcc4e6c232: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:e1b9602163a9c0959d924315aaf3919aa2404baa88997f11073758dfe43c7714
Status: Downloaded newer image for frappe/erpnext-worker:edge
Pulling traefik (traefik:v2.2)...
v2.2: Pulling from library/traefik
cbdbe7a5bc2a: Pull complete
f16506d32a25: Pull complete
605303653d66: Pull complete
a9005a35b171: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ea0aa8832bfd08369166baecd40b35fc58979df8f5dc5182e4e63ee6adbe66db
Status: Downloaded newer image for traefik:v2.2
Pulling mariadb (mariadb:10.3)...
10.3: Pulling from library/mariadb
e6ca3592b144: Pull complete
534a5505201d: Pull complete
990916bd23bb: Pull complete
c62d6bd206a2: Pull complete
ba34deb445c3: Pull complete
47b4f6570cf0: Pull complete
28b039c5139e: Pull complete
d9f0e67eb23f: Pull complete
69df87d9330c: Pull complete
420ae5e12220: Pull complete
7539ff915a5c: Pull complete
45aee0e8778e: Pull complete
694594587433: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:bc0a542b4b69b71b4dda09aaaec3cb57902f935fc1237ee9bd542a944a877ae8
Status: Downloaded newer image for mariadb:10.3
Pulling erpnext-nginx (frappe/erpnext-nginx:edge)...
edge: Pulling from frappe/erpnext-nginx
d121f8d1c412: Already exists
ebd81fc8c071: Already exists
655316c160af: Already exists
d15953c0e0f8: Already exists
2ee525c5c3cc: Already exists
998e31db18de: Pull complete
d6b501d3e02a: Pull complete
95b354c2b5ea: Pull complete
8ef9ced566c5: Pull complete
7359850e2e7d: Pull complete
b1ddb017a0ed: Pull complete
055262deb169: Pull complete
4155a56e936b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:394dd647bf0d486afc689366dff7cac6fca9fd623c47ec55583d53581431b91c
Status: Downloaded newer image for frappe/erpnext-nginx:edge
Pulling frappe-socketio (frappe/frappe-socketio:edge)...
edge: Pulling from frappe/frappe-socketio
abb454610128: Already exists
3dfc5a66c517: Already exists
9d3cc0392eb2: Already exists
269452c05570: Already exists
4a5ad82bcf62: Already exists
d9e4710f1239: Pull complete
0cbfca669cac: Pull complete
c1659af7c53f: Pull complete
7d1fb7ca8900: Pull complete
5b751fa50a09: Pull complete
a51353f97821: Pull complete
db61d40e1d8f: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:43abae19ff0f2ab064bfae012c77b7515534a7294ea05c65738ce943818758ff
Status: Downloaded newer image for frappe/frappe-socketio:edge
Creating frappe_docker_redis-cache_1    ... done
Creating frappe_docker_redis-socketio_1 ... done
Creating frappe_docker_mariadb_1                ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-nginx_1  ... done
Creating frappe_docker_redis-queue_1     ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-python_1 ... done
Creating frappe_docker_traefik_1        ... 
Creating frappe_docker_traefik_1                ... error
Creating frappe_docker_frappe-socketio_1 ... 
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-long_1 ... 
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-schedule_1    ... 
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-short_1 ... 
Creating frappe_docker_site-creator_1           ... done
Creating frappe_docker_frappe-socketio_1        ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-long_1    ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-schedule_1       ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-short_1   ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-default_1 ... done

ERROR: for traefik  Cannot start service traefik: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint frappe_docker_traefik_1 (9403a83dff1da9718f4bbe0bf9c308b7a69093a4aab714a45d542224e8c9679c): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
root $
```

and:

```
root $ 
root $ sudo netstat -pna | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      892/nginx: master p 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:40868       172.217.3.174:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:34876       172.217.14.226:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:49400       198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:45006       172.217.3.161:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:57728       99.84.66.47:443         ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:41922       216.58.193.67:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:41330       157.240.3.29:443        ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:55040       69.147.80.15:443        ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:54386       172.217.3.206:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:40868       104.16.24.34:443        ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:45212       172.217.14.194:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:58514       172.217.14.206:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:48780       216.58.193.66:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:54460       216.58.193.78:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:49406       198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:48966       74.125.197.95:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:56798       98.137.11.143:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:43260       172.217.14.193:443      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:43158       172.217.14.202:443      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:43156       172.217.14.202:443      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:46862       151.101.193.69:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:55550       192.0.73.2:443          ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:52392       172.217.3.194:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:34928       172.217.14.226:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:60420       172.217.3.195:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:48100       74.125.195.189:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:52396       172.217.3.194:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:48774       216.58.193.66:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:42918       192.184.69.141:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:53542       54.212.130.172:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:52372       172.217.3.194:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:34266       172.217.14.198:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:44174       216.58.217.34:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:59974       74.125.20.156:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:57814       99.84.66.47:443         ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:49482       198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:39464       23.62.70.19:443         ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:35576       99.84.66.78:443         ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:59108       157.240.3.20:443        ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:43230       172.217.14.193:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:39030       172.217.3.164:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:39160       104.17.79.107:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:54458       216.58.193.78:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:41854       172.217.3.170:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        1      0 192.168.1.3:53892       172.67.11.174:80        CLOSE_WAIT  446443/WebKitNetwor 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:45222       172.217.14.194:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:45108       54.70.109.38:443        ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:49452       198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:48836       216.58.193.66:443       ESTABLISHED 426645/firefox      
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      892/nginx: master p 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     24632463 448102/containerd-s  @/containerd-shim/moby/adaa8c3f4f239d443191aa03c37d4f9b2dc5867f355327bf9ac454c04228c421/shim.sock@
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21327443 1/systemd            /run/systemd/userdb/io.systemd.DynamicUser
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONNECTED     24588159 446443/WebKitNetwor  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24212443 426457/python3       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24588530 446443/WebKitNetwor  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24433290 1/systemd            /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24588523 446443/WebKitNetwor  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24433288 438233/fwupd         
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONNECTED     24588536 446443/WebKitNetwor  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24433306 438233/fwupd         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24432328 616/dbus-daemon      /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24628094 448102/containerd-s  @/containerd-shim/moby/adaa8c3f4f239d443191aa03c37d4f9b2dc5867f355327bf9ac454c04228c421/shim.sock@
root $
```

My understanding of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37971961/4531180) is that it relates more to running the container rather than building the image.  Yet the image wasn't built?  I don't see it listed in `docker images`, and certainly nothing recent.

This is almost certainly a conflict with an existing container?

Comment: From your netstat output it looks as though you have an nginx process bound to port 443.

Comment: yes, I think that's a docker container.  I'll kill it and then the image should build?

Comment: I can't say for certain, but it will likely get you past the "address already in use" error.

Answer (score 1):

thought it was working because `docker-compose build` returned without errors.

I've tried a few URL's, but can't quite tell what happened:

```
root $ 
root $ docker-compose up
Starting frappe_docker_erpnext-nginx_1 ... 
frappe_docker_mariadb_1 is up-to-date
frappe_docker_redis-cache_1 is up-to-date
Starting frappe_docker_traefik_1       ... 
frappe_docker_erpnext-python_1 is up-to-date
frappe_docker_redis-socketio_1 is up-to-date
frappe_docker_redis-queue_1 is up-to-date
Starting frappe_docker_site-creator_1  ... 
frappe_docker_frappe-socketio_1 is up-to-date
frappe_docker_erpnext-schedule_1 is up-to-date
Starting frappe_docker_erpnext-nginx_1 ... done
Starting frappe_docker_traefik_1       ... done
Starting frappe_docker_site-creator_1  ... done
Attaching to frappe_docker_mariadb_1, frappe_docker_redis-cache_1, frappe_docker_erpnext-python_1, frappe_docker_redis-socketio_1, frappe_docker_redis-queue_1, frappe_docker_frappe-socketio_1, frappe_docker_erpnext-schedule_1, frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-default_1, frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-short_1, frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-long_1, frappe_docker_site-creator_1, frappe_docker_erpnext-nginx_1, frappe_docker_traefik_1
erpnext-python_1          | Attempt 1 to connect to mariadb:3306
erpnext-python_1          | Attempt 2 to connect to mariadb:3306
erpnext-python_1          | Attempt 3 to connect to mariadb:3306
erpnext-python_1          | Attempt 4 to connect to mariadb:3306
erpnext-python_1          | Attempt 5 to connect to mariadb:3306
erpnext-python_1          | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-queue:6379
erpnext-python_1          | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-cache:6379
erpnext-python_1          | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-socketio:6379
erpnext-python_1          | Connections OK
erpnext-python_1          | [2020-09-24 21:42:51 +0000] [20] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.10.0
erpnext-python_1          | [2020-09-24 21:42:51 +0000] [20] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (20)
erpnext-python_1          | [2020-09-24 21:42:51 +0000] [20] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
erpnext-python_1          | [2020-09-24 21:42:51 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
erpnext-python_1          | [2020-09-24 21:42:51 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
erpnext-schedule_1        | Attempt 1 to connect to mariadb:3306
erpnext-schedule_1        | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-queue:6379
erpnext-schedule_1        | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-cache:6379
erpnext-schedule_1        | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-socketio:6379
erpnext-schedule_1        | Connections OK
erpnext-schedule_1        | Starting background scheduler . . .
erpnext-worker-long_1     | Attempt 1 to connect to mariadb:3306
erpnext-worker-long_1     | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-queue:6379
erpnext-worker-long_1     | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-cache:6379
erpnext-worker-long_1     | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-socketio:6379
erpnext-worker-long_1     | Connections OK
erpnext-worker-long_1     | 21:42:50 Worker rq:worker:9e230e83f0a54f2c9e23cf8c05803a5b.d7c672c3b8e4.13.long: started, version 1.5.2
erpnext-worker-long_1     | 21:42:50 *** Listening on long...
erpnext-worker-long_1     | 21:42:50 Cleaning registries for queue: long
erpnext-worker-short_1    | Attempt 1 to connect to mariadb:3306
erpnext-worker-short_1    | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-queue:6379
erpnext-worker-short_1    | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-cache:6379
erpnext-worker-short_1    | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-socketio:6379
erpnext-worker-short_1    | Connections OK
erpnext-worker-short_1    | 21:42:50 Worker rq:worker:2b7b866af6af496fa729c4ad20e78978.7da607a8d5a8.13.short: started, version 1.5.2
erpnext-worker-short_1    | 21:42:50 *** Listening on short...
erpnext-worker-short_1    | 21:42:50 Cleaning registries for queue: short
redis-queue_1             | 1:C 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.656 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-queue_1             | 1:C 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.656 # Redis version=6.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-queue_1             | 1:C 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.656 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis-queue_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.657 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
redis-queue_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.658 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis-queue_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.658 # Server initialized
redis-queue_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.658 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis-queue_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.658 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.8
redis-queue_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.658 * RDB age 37 seconds
redis-queue_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.658 * RDB memory usage when created 0.83 Mb
redis-queue_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.658 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis-queue_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.658 * Ready to accept connections
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.3.24+maria~focal started.
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.3.24+maria~focal started.
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:16 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.24-MariaDB-1:10.3.24+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.24 started; log sequence number 39389994; transaction id 12198
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:31 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:32 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:32 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@ae9b03a0d7ee' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:32 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:32 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:42:32 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mariadb_1                 | Version: '10.3.24-MariaDB-1:10.3.24+maria~focal'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
mariadb_1                 | 2020-09-24 21:43:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200924 21:43:04
erpnext-worker-default_1  | Attempt 1 to connect to mariadb:3306
erpnext-worker-default_1  | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-queue:6379
erpnext-worker-default_1  | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-cache:6379
erpnext-worker-default_1  | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-socketio:6379
erpnext-worker-default_1  | Connections OK
erpnext-worker-default_1  | 21:42:50 Worker rq:worker:1c434d0c9d5d4d61874e73a1eab8cad6.f18a505e3d01.14.default: started, version 1.5.2
erpnext-worker-default_1  | 21:42:50 *** Listening on default...
erpnext-worker-default_1  | 21:42:50 Cleaning registries for queue: default
redis-cache_1             | 1:C 24 Sep 2020 21:42:19.998 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-cache_1             | 1:C 24 Sep 2020 21:42:19.998 # Redis version=6.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-cache_1             | 1:C 24 Sep 2020 21:42:19.998 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.000 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.266 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.266 # Server initialized
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.266 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.267 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.8
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.267 * RDB age 37 seconds
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.267 * RDB memory usage when created 1.33 Mb
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.269 * DB loaded from disk: 0.003 seconds
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:20.269 * Ready to accept connections
frappe-socketio_1         | listening on *: 9000
redis-socketio_1          | 1:C 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.894 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-socketio_1          | 1:C 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.894 # Redis version=6.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-socketio_1          | 1:C 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.894 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis-socketio_1          | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.895 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
redis-socketio_1          | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.896 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis-socketio_1          | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.896 # Server initialized
redis-socketio_1          | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.896 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis-socketio_1          | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.896 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.8
redis-socketio_1          | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.896 * RDB age 41 seconds
redis-socketio_1          | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.896 * RDB memory usage when created 0.79 Mb
redis-socketio_1          | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.896 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis-socketio_1          | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:42:24.896 * Ready to accept connections
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from flags."
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=info msg="Traefik version 2.2.11 built on 2020-09-07T14:12:48Z"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Static configuration loaded {\"global\":{\"checkNewVersion\":true},\"serversTransport\":{\"maxIdleConnsPerHost\":200},\"entryPoints\":{\"web\":{\"address\":\":80\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":180000000000}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{},\"http\":{}},\"websecure\":{\"address\":\":443\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":180000000000}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{},\"http\":{}}},\"providers\":{\"providersThrottleDuration\":2000000000,\"docker\":{\"watch\":true,\"endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"defaultRule\":\"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)\",\"swarmModeRefreshSeconds\":15000000000}},\"log\":{\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"format\":\"common\"},\"certificatesResolvers\":{\"myresolver\":{\"acme\":{\"email\":\"saunders.nicholas@gmail.com\",\"caServer\":\"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"storage\":\"/letsencrypt/acme.json\",\"keyType\":\"RSA4096\",\"httpChallenge\":{\"entryPoint\":\"web\"}}}}}"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://docs.traefik.io/contributing/data-collection/\n"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=info msg="Starting provider aggregator.ProviderAggregator {}"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Start TCP Server" entryPointName=web
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Start TCP Server" entryPointName=websecure
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *acme.Provider {\"email\":\"saunders.nicholas@gmail.com\",\"caServer\":\"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"storage\":\"/letsencrypt/acme.json\",\"keyType\":\"RSA4096\",\"httpChallenge\":{\"entryPoint\":\"web\"},\"ResolverName\":\"myresolver\",\"store\":{},\"ChallengeStore\":{}}"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=info msg="Testing certificate renew..." providerName=myresolver.acme
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {\"watch\":true,\"endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"defaultRule\":\"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)\",\"swarmModeRefreshSeconds\":15000000000}"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider myresolver.acme: {\"http\":{},\"tls\":{}}" providerName=myresolver.acme
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *traefik.Provider {}"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider internal: {\"http\":{\"services\":{\"noop\":{}}},\"tcp\":{},\"tls\":{}}" providerName=internal
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 19.03.11 (API 1.40)" providerName=docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=frappe-socketio-frappe-docker-547893b784969e960c010590b90d256a5844d4eda6bef53402117f25fd6cd835
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=erpnext-worker-long-frappe-docker-d7c672c3b8e46b1ddbdea4540aaae117852a22cdc04cbddb6a4c9aa5f678849b
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=erpnext-schedule-frappe-docker-16916a30304b6f542c219ed353f1c924fcd6d9142f4ab17e101eab8adc3b2f4f
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=erpnext-worker-default-frappe-docker-f18a505e3d01d1fc0741cfdc15ff33d0188e9e4de5852e3c760eb22a066749b9
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=erpnext-worker-short-frappe-docker-7da607a8d5a81077d1dd500f9ed6888f84cfbcbd7dd2efab11565611a66f2e2a
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=site-creator-frappe-docker-6ea0246bf12dbaf11c684dbecc9dd449b30f38930610b3a6bdd6fcc31a416b92
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=mariadb-frappe-docker-70879517dbbf4ed9c84627f8b312709a56832e423df82715ad0db82c1ed5321b
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=redis-socketio-frappe-docker-e1b06e870f32304b7dcc863a2fef341d0642a929cd721a9220af1c9f845cdf9c
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=erpnext-python-frappe-docker-b8ef2a1cd6858a6a7aa2517928dddffc2dfde713090a6d160847a641288521c6
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=redis-cache-frappe-docker-d7cbac8c826b3c00cb5a699d89d8dd261b6efecdcf75e0e5117459b3a2b1ac57
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=redis-queue-frappe-docker-4d6c6ed96e2a4da4d7efa21299e6ea9fb74f09bdc466fd878598f5cd288090ad
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:16Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"erpnext-nginx\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"websecure\"],\"service\":\"erpnext-nginx\",\"rule\":\"Host(`erp.saundersconsulting.tech)\",\"tls\":{\"certResolver\":\"myresolver\"}},\"http-catchall\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"web\"],\"middlewares\":[\"redirect-to-https\"],\"service\":\"traefik-frappe-docker\",\"rule\":\"hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)\"}},\"services\":{\"erpnext-nginx\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://172.20.0.4:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}},\"traefik-frappe-docker\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://172.20.0.14:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}}},\"middlewares\":{\"redirect-to-https\":{\"redirectScheme\":{\"scheme\":\"https\"}}}},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{}}" providerName=docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining entryPointName=web routerName=http-catchall@docker serviceName=traefik-frappe-docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" entryPointName=web routerName=http-catchall@docker serviceName=traefik-frappe-docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://172.20.0.14:80" entryPointName=web routerName=http-catchall@docker serverName=0 serviceName=traefik-frappe-docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware traefik-frappe-docker" middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=web routerName=http-catchall@docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=RedirectScheme entryPointName=web routerName=http-catchall@docker middlewareName=redirect-to-https@docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection to https " middlewareType=RedirectScheme entryPointName=web routerName=http-catchall@docker middlewareName=redirect-to-https@docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" entryPointName=web routerName=http-catchall@docker middlewareName=redirect-to-https@docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=web middlewareType=Recovery middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" routerName=erpnext-nginx@docker serviceName=erpnext-nginx middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining entryPointName=websecure
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" entryPointName=websecure routerName=erpnext-nginx@docker serviceName=erpnext-nginx
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://172.20.0.4:80" entryPointName=websecure routerName=erpnext-nginx@docker serviceName=erpnext-nginx serverName=0
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware erpnext-nginx" middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder routerName=erpnext-nginx@docker entryPointName=websecure
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=error msg="error while parsing rule Host(`erp.saundersconsulting.tech): 1:6: raw string literal not terminated" routerName=erpnext-nginx@docker entryPointName=websecure
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=websecure middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:17Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:18Z" level=error msg="Error parsing domains in provider ACME: 1:6: raw string literal not terminated" providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=erpnext-nginx@docker rule="Host(`erp.saundersconsulting.tech)"
site-creator_1            | Attempt 1 to connect to mariadb:3306
site-creator_1            | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-queue:6379
site-creator_1            | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-cache:6379
site-creator_1            | Attempt 1 to connect to redis-socketio:6379
site-creator_1            | Connections OK
site-creator_1            | Site erp.saundersconsulting.tech already exists
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:26Z" level=debug msg="Provider event received {Status:die ID:6ea0246bf12dbaf11c684dbecc9dd449b30f38930610b3a6bdd6fcc31a416b92 From:frappe/erpnext-worker:edge Type:container Action:die Actor:{ID:6ea0246bf12dbaf11c684dbecc9dd449b30f38930610b3a6bdd6fcc31a416b92 Attributes:map[com.docker.compose.config-
```

...

```
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:30Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" container=redis-queue-frappe-docker-4d6c6ed96e2a4da4d7efa21299e6ea9fb74f09bdc466fd878598f5cd288090ad providerName=docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:30Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"erpnext-nginx\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"websecure\"],\"service\":\"erpnext-nginx\",\"rule\":\"Host(`erp.saundersconsulting.tech)\",\"tls\":{\"certResolver\":\"myresolver\"}},\"http-catchall\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"web\"],\"middlewares\":[\"redirect-to-https\"],\"service\":\"traefik-frappe-docker\",\"rule\":\"hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)\"}},\"services\":{\"erpnext-nginx\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://172.20.0.4:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}},\"traefik-frappe-docker\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://172.20.0.14:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}}},\"middlewares\":{\"redirect-to-https\":{\"redirectScheme\":{\"scheme\":\"https\"}}}},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{}}" providerName=docker
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:46:30Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration" providerName=docker
erpnext-nginx_1           | Waiting for frappe-python to be available on erpnext-python port 8000
erpnext-nginx_1           | Frappe-python available on erpnext-python port 8000
erpnext-nginx_1           | Waiting for frappe-socketio to be available on frappe-socketio port 9000
erpnext-nginx_1           | Frappe-socketio available on frappe-socketio port 9000
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:47:21.055 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:47:21.056 * Background saving started by pid 18
redis-cache_1             | 18:C 24 Sep 2020 21:47:21.107 * DB saved on disk
redis-cache_1             | 18:C 24 Sep 2020 21:47:21.108 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
redis-cache_1             | 1:M 24 Sep 2020 21:47:21.156 * Background saving terminated with success
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:50:09Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"localhost\""
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:50:09Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:40102: remote error: tls: bad certificate"
traefik_1                 | time="2020-09-24T21:50:14Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"localhost\""
```

Looking at the below `entrypoint`:

```
root $ 
root $ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
547893b78496        frappe/frappe-socketio:edge   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes                                                  frappe_docker_frappe-socketio_1
d7c672c3b8e4        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-long_1
16916a30304b        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_erpnext-schedule_1
f18a505e3d01        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-default_1
7da607a8d5a8        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-short_1
70879517dbbf        mariadb:10.3                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       3306/tcp                                   frappe_docker_mariadb_1
e1b06e870f32        redis:latest                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       6379/tcp                                   frappe_docker_redis-socketio_1
b8ef2a1cd685        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_erpnext-python_1
d6555ff0f12f        traefik:v2.2                  "/entrypoint.sh --lo…"   11 minutes ago      Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   frappe_docker_traefik_1
d7cbac8c826b        redis:latest                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       6379/tcp                                   frappe_docker_redis-cache_1
55b3a31ee25c        frappe/erpnext-nginx:edge     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   11 minutes ago      Up 7 minutes        80/tcp                                     frappe_docker_erpnext-nginx_1
4d6c6ed96e2a        redis:latest                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       6379/tcp                                   frappe_docker_redis-queue_1
root $
```

I tried a few of those ports, best result was a `404` from `localhost` on Firefox which I *think* was from this unconfigured app.

Quite possibly everything's working as intended, but simply needs configuration.